# Getting javascript object back from DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

Say I create a javascript class as follows:

```
class DivClass {
  constructor () {
    this.div1 = document.createElement('div')
    this.div1.id = 'div1'
  }
}
```

Later I instantiate the class as follows:

```
var divObject = new DivClass()
parentDiv.appendChild(divObject.div1)
```

and the DIV eventually appears in the DOM.

If I was to locate the 'div1' element within the DOM, say via getElementById() for argument sake, is there anyway of getting back to the javascript 'divObject' responsible for its creation?

From what little I've learned about javascript, I kind of get the impression that the translation from javascript API to DOM is a one way trip and this just simply isn't possible.

Apologies in advance if I've gotten any of the terminology wrong, but I'm kind of new to javascript and still don't fully understand the DOM/API relationship.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *simply isn't possible* — correct, unless you establish some framework for making that possible.

Comment: This isn't possible, but what's your [actual motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  to do this? You already have the original class in memory, so you can put it into a data structure and call it up by name. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)? It doesn't seem to follow that process, you don't call `customElements.define()`, and it's not a subclass of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: `parentDiv.appendChild(divObject)` throws Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: `parentDiv.appendChild(divObject.div1)` works fine though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a reference to the object to the DIV element.

```
class DivClass {
  constructor () {
    this.div1 = document.createElement('div')
    this.div1.id = 'div1'
    this.div1.divClass = this;
  }
}
```

Then you can use `document.getElementById("div1").divClass` to get the object.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause memory problems, as the garbage collector couldn't clean up instance of `DivClass` instances if the elements still existed in the DOM? I think this is how jQuery used to do `data()` until they had issues...

Comment: That's by design, not a problem. If you need to be able to get the object from the DOM element, then it shouldn't be cleaned up until the DOM element goes away.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm not doing anything useful at the moment, just trying to familiarise myself with how the DOM and API relate to one another. Thanks ever so much for your advice, and for overlooking the code error highlighted by the other kind people above.

Comment: I asked about the code error above. I almost didn't post this answer because I didn't understand what you're doing.